# custom windows title bar and hide default one

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i already create my own custom windows title bar for my android app but now every time i open the app i see for a second the default title bar yet i tried to put transparent background but doesnt work heres my code:

```
custom_title.xml: 
<resources>
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>

 </style>
```

any help ill appreciate, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try `full screen` Activity?Or `noTitleBar` theme for your Activity?Then create a layout for Activity that has sub layout looks like your custom title bar,which it is first in it.For example your layout may be look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <your custom title bar/>
    <your main layout/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So when your Activity propose for user,default title bar is not visible and your custom layout(that you include in your layout) seems as title bar.

Comment: i have this `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"` so i call my customtheme for titlebar but i still see the default one for 1 second and then i can see correctly my titlebar

Comment: i saw this: **According to this article, the best way to draw a title bar is to ignore FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE and instead just draw the title bar as part of your main view. This would not only avoid the flashing** what u think its this what u telling me to do?

Comment: great i figure it out with your example now i understand, thanks very much.

Comment: @alexistkd Do not forget you can use `include` or `merge` in your layout.

Comment: thank u very much u save my life almost i was all day trying to figure it out this. thanks again